# backbone filter collection to return models by name?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

I am trying to filter a collection a collection by a models attribute (name),

```
byName: function(searchParam) {
    var filtered = this.filter(function(model){
        console.log(model.get('name').toLowerCase());
        console.log(searchParam.toLowerCase());
        if(model.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchParam.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
            model.trigger('show');
        } else {
            model.trigger('hide');
        }
    });
}
```

I am having a small problem though, my search parameter at the moment is just simply "a". It should therefore be returning all models that have a name with "a" in it.

However I have 2 models that should be returned the names of these are "abba" and "AAAS". I was assuming that "AAAS" was not being return as my search terms was lowercase, and the model name was uppercase, so I added a `.toLowerCase()` but it still only returns "abba" why?

Comment: I made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xemn0otk/1/) and your code returns abba and AAAS. So the problem is something else, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation of [`_.filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) (Backbone's `Collection.filter` uses it), your `filtered` array should be empty - it should contain only elements, which **predicate** returned truthy value - your function returns `undefined` which is falsy value. Try this:

```
...
if(model.get('name').toLowerCase().indexOf(searchParam.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
    model.trigger('show');
    return true;
} else {
    model.trigger('hide');
}
...
```

Now `filtered` should contain all models with `searchParam` in it's `name` (case insensitive).

Comment: It's worth adding that if you don't *need* the `filtered` array of models in the rest of the `byName(...)` method, you're better off using the `each(...)` method.  I.e.  `this.each(function(model) { ... }`.